# Does a virtual in a method of a c++ class trickle down to it's children

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

Why will the method of the subclass on the bottom of the tree be executed in this example?
I thought that the virtual only means that if I execute the method via a pointer of the class, but that one is actually pointing to an instance of a subclass, it will execute the method of the subclass. But apparently it will do this if any of the parents defined the method as virtual. Can someone explain why that is and what a best practise is for using virtual? (I was taught to put it in front of all the methods that override the Base Classes virtual method)
Here's the Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass
{
    public:
    virtual void myFunc()=0;
};
class Child1: public BaseClass
{
    public:
    void myFunc(){
        std::cout << "Child1\n";
    }
};
class Child2: public Child1
{
    public:
    void myFunc(){
        std::cout << "Child2\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;
    Child1 * p = &c1;
    p->myFunc();
    p = & c2;
    p->myFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

This will print "Child1" and "Child2" instead of "Child1" twice, as it would without the virtual. What would I have to do to have a virtual method with my expected result?

Comment: Yes, `virtual` makes all descendant functions `virtual` as well. I try to stick with the guidance that each virtual function should have exactly one of the `virtual`, `override`, or `final` keyword to indicate that it's virtual and where in the inheritance hierarchy it is.

Comment: Yes, this is how dynamic polymorphism works. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: You _can_ mark a class's override of a virtual function as `final`, which will prevent further descendants from writing their own implementation. That would cause your current code to fail to compile, though, because if `Child1::myFunc` were final then `Child2` would be attempting to override it. I don't think there's a way to split the difference and turn off virtuality while still allowing descendants to override the function.

Comment: Yeah there is no equivalent of the "new" keyword that C# has for hiding the base class function...

Comment: The linked question was helpfull thanks @ChrisMM  (And sorry for a duplicate) And Nathan Pierson answered the second part of my question. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

This is the meaning of the polymorphism.

If you have a pointer to a base class (the so-called static type of the pointer) that is assigned with a pointer to a derived class (the so-called dynamic type of the pointer) then virtual functions will be searched in the table of virtual function pointers in the  actual pointed derived class.

In your program the class `Child2` is a derived class of the class `Child1`

```
class Child2: public Child1
{
    //...
};
```

The class `Child1` is a base class for the class `Child2`. The class `Child2` overrides the virtual function `myFunc` of its base class `Child1`.